# AutoSuggestBox (UWP) binding through code behind when using Reactive UI

Tags: uwp, reactiveui

Reactive UI document suggests to use code behind binding instead of XAML binding to avoid memory leaks. I am trying to bind a `SearchCommand` present in a view model to the `AutoSuggestBox`.

`SearchView.xaml`

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="SearchBox" QueryIcon="Find"/>
```

`SearchView.xaml.cs`

```
this.BindCommand(ViewModel,
    viewModel => viewModel.SearchCommand,
    view => view.SearchBox);
```

However this does not work, the command does not get invoked. I also tried binding the `QuerySubmitted` event, but I don't find it in the `Events()` below. I used `ReactiveUI.Events` package

`SearchView.xaml.cs`

```
this.Events().QuerySubmitted
    .InvokeCommand(this, x => x.ViewModel.SearchCommand)
```

Comment: To get access to the QuerySubmitted event you need to do SearchBox.Events().QuerySubmitted. And as for BindCommand, you probably have to explicitly specify which event you want your command binded to. You can do that with the optional string parameter called toEvent: nameof(SearchBox.QuerySubmitted)

Comment: @ColtBauman It worked

Comment: Out of curiosity, which one worked out for you?

Comment: SearchBox.Events(), I haven't tried the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to the QuerySubmitted event you need to do SearchBox.Events().QuerySubmitted. And as for BindCommand, you probably have to explicitly specify which event you want your command binded to. You can do that with the optional string parameter called toEvent: nameof(SearchBox.QuerySubmitted)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it with binding the command directly, but usually I bind to the property and then listen for changes.

```
this.Bind(ViewModel,
viewModel => viewModel.SearchTerm,
view => view.SearchBox);
```

and then in your view model

```
private string _searchTerm;

public string SearchTerm
{
    get => _searchTerm;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _searchTerm, value);
}
```

and then inside of the constructor

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchTerm).Subscribe(_ => SearchCommand());
```

this is not tested, maybe not even the best way of doing it, but this is how I have been doing it